# Converting Service Area polygons to raster using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, service-area

I have just made some very nice service area polygons and would like to convert these to rasters for further analysis. When I try polygon to raster (field: to break), it results in an empty raster. I thought maybe there is a problem because there are so many different polygons... so I attempted to dissolve the polygons according to break values, but the resulting polygon shapes are totally different from the ones in the service area analysis. In other words, the shapes from the network analysis are not preserved.

Why?

Update: Here is a screenshot of the map and assoc. attribute table.

TO respond to one comment: I have tried to export them as polygons, but when converting these to raster, the shape is not preserved, assuming because there are so many polygons involved. Wish there was a simple fix to this for quick analysis of network polygons and service area findings. I have uploaded a screenshot the raster result as well.[image: map][image: resultingraster]

Comment: Can you please edit your question including a) an image of your service area polygons and b) a print of their attribute table with a focus on the "to break" field?

Comment: original poster here - writing from home computer. I left work before i saw the request for screenshots and unfortunately cannot upload the exact image from home. I dont want to lose any time though so I've done my best to simulate the problem exactly with some data at home. I will repost with the original pics tomorrow morning when I get to the office. The first is a pic of the SA polygons, the second is a pic of the associated attribute table with From Break and To Break columns, which were referenced in the original post. Many thanks!!
[![map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51jkH.png)](https://i

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164121)

Comment: This is an edit from the same person, but different users. It isn't a comment

Comment: Have you exported the Service Area Polygons to a new feature class?